# Checking for existence of Windows API Functions

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I am new to Windows programming and I'm trying to discover the best way to check for the existence of Windows Shell API functions. I want to use some of the new taskbar features in Windows7.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460%28VS.85%29.aspx#custom_jump_lists

But I still want my program to be usable by previous versions of Windows. Is there an easy way to know if the functions are available to be called in the end users system. I'm programming in C++.

Comment: [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx) will be your friends. Also, check out [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/XDllPt4.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

It depends on the kinds of the functions.

For plain (non-COM) functions, the only way is to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. If either fails, you know the OS is missing that function. Writing those function pointer type declarations for function pointers duplicating existing function signatures can be tedious, though in VC++2010 you can use `decltype` for that. For example:

```
HMODULE user32 = LoadLibraryW(L"user32");
if (user32 != NULL)
{
    auto messageBoxW = reinterpret_cast<decltype(MessageBoxW)*>(GetProcAddress(user32, "MessageBoxW"));
    if (messageBoxW != NULL)
    {
        messageBoxW(HWND_DESKTOP, L"Hello!", NULL, MB_OK);
    }
}
```

However, many Shell APIs are exposed via COM components and interfaces. Those cases are different. Sometimes you need to deal with entirely new components; e.g. `IApplicationDestinations` is a new interface in Win7, and the coclass that implements it is also new. In those cases, you can just do `CoCreateInstance`, and check the return value for `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` - this means that such coclass isn't registered on the system (and, effectively, isn't supported).

Sometimes, however, new OS versions introduce new interfaces on existing coclasses. An example is `ITaskbarList3`, new in Win7, but provided on existing coclass that implements `ITaskbarList` and dates back to Win95. In those cases, you should first instantiate the coclass for the most basic interface, and then use `QueryInterface` to obtain new interface versions, and detect that they're not supported by checking return value for `E_NOINTERFACE`.

Comment: *"For plain (non-COM) functions, the only way is to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`."* - Not quite the only way. There is a much cleaner solution actually: Use of the [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls).

Comment: How to gracefully handle the case where the function (or the library) doesn't exist, with delay loading?

Comment: That's explained under [Error Handling and Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification).

Answer (score 2):

I believe MSDN is your best bet for this. Every MSDN page for a function's documentation contains a section in the end which states that which version of Windows support this function.

As an example, Check the doumentation of [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199(VS.85).aspx). This contains a section named **Requirements** under which there is a field **Minimum Supported Client** and **Minimum Supported Server**.

However, if you want to check for the existence of functions dynamically, then you can do this through [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, the MSDN doesn't document, which system introduced any particular Windows API call. It only documents, which supported versions of Windows offer a particular API call. Unless the documentation hasn't been updated at all recently, the supported client doesn't go back any further than Windows Vista currently, even if an API has existed for decades.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the currrent solutions. You'll end up with quite a bit of unreadable code.

A nicer alternative is to wrap the functionality in a custom Windows 7-only DLL. For other systems, provide another version of the DLL that implements the same functions. This can often be a no-op. E.g. a function to set the taskbar extensions would be a no-op on older Windows versions.

The dynamic switching between these DLLs is done by using the delay-load feature of MSVC. You can use a custom hook in your EXE to pick the correct DLL version when the first function in your DLL is called, at which time you know whether you're running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

you should use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to dynamically load and invoke the new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can always check for the existence of function within a library at runtime and take suitable actions.
Check the LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress APIs.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out at compile time so as to get a build break if the function is not available on the OS you are targetting (eg Win 95), then you can define some macros, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745(VS.85).aspx):NTDDI_VERSION, _WIN32_WINNT, WINVER.

If you want your app to work fine when the functionality is not available (eg JumpLists on OSes older than Win7), then you should do combination of LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress to figure out whether the function you are looking for is available.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LoadLibarary` to get library handle and `GerProcAddress` to get pointer to a function. For those functions that are not supported by current OS you will get `ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED` error from `GetLastError`.