# How to conditionally execute function if operating system supports it?

Tags: windows, backwards-compatibility

I'd like to build an application that invokes [CancelIoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows Vista and newer (where it is supported) and does something else on Windows XP (where it is not).

1. What happens if I compile the application under Windows 7 but run it under Windows XP? What will happen at runtime? Will I get some sort of load error?
2. How do I get my application to pick one code path or another (avoiding load errors) depending on what operating system is being used at runtime? Please provide sample code.

**UPDATE**: Please note that the DLL exists on Windows XP but the function does not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delay Loading DLLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388388/delay-loading-dlls)

Comment: @GregHewgill, delay loading isn't appropriate in this case (dynamic loading is). Aside from that, I believe this isn't an exact duplicate because #1 isn't covered, nor is it clear how to detect which OS is running in #2.

Comment: The way to detect the OS is *not* to detect the specific OS, but simply try to load the DLL. You want feature detection, not version detection. The feature is explained in the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx

Comment: @GregHewgill, if you take a look at the documentation for CancelIoEx() you will note the DLL in question is Kernel32.dll. The DLL is not missing. The function is. As such, I don't believe delay-loading applies.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread your question. I've provided an answer that should work by way of apology. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking for existance of Windows API Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129340/checking-for-existance-of-windows-api-functions), [How to call a kernel32.dll function GetTickCount() using LoadLibrary(..) in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557028/how-to-call-a-kernel32-dll-function-gettickcount-using-loadlibrary-in-c)

Comment: Not blaming you for asking a duplicate question, of course. If you didn't know about `LoadLibrary` or `GetProcAddress`, you'd have a hard time finding them. I just like to keep all answers in one place. Call it an obsession. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an application that references a non-existent DLL export will fail to load.

Adding code to take different paths based on the OS version won't help much, because you'll still have the reference to the non-existent function.

Instead, you need to resolve the reference at run-time.

One option is Delay Load Import (with the `/DELAYLOAD` linker flag), but I don't think this is supported for the core system DLLs (like kernel32).

The other is to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.  The code is something like this, though in reality you'd do the lookup once when your app starts, not each time you call the function.

```
// Declare type of pointer to CancelIoEx function
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *CancelIoExType)(HANDLE hFile, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);

// Load module; won't fail because it's already imported
HMODULE hKernel32 = LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");
// Look up function address
CancelIoExType pCancelIoEx = (CancelIoExType)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "CancelIoEx");
// Do something with it
if (pCancelIoEx)
{
    // Function exists so call it
    pCancelIoEx(hMyFile, pMyOverlapped);
}
else
{
    // Function doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve a symbol at runtime, you need to use [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HMODULE kernel32 = LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll");
BOOL (WINAPI *pCancelIoEx)(HANDLE, LPOVERLAPPED) = GetProcAddress(kernel32, "CancelIoEx");
```

In the case that `CancelIoEx` is not available, you will get `NULL` back from `GetProcAddress`. Once you have the pointer (you only need to do the above once), you can call it normally with:

```
pCancelIoEx(h, &lp);
```